# Android Studio can't connect to JFrog Artifactory

Tags: android, android-studio, ssl-certificate, artifactory

We've been successfully running a JFrog Artifactory OSS instance for a few years to host our Android libraries. Recently the web server certificate expired so we replaced it with a legitimate (not self signed) one.

This instantly plunged all the developers and build server into chaos.

Sometimes we get this message:

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Mostly Android Studio just spits out this message:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@***/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.test.packagename
```

We've tried adding the certificate to our Android Studio, we've tried upgrading and restarting Artifactory and the server and nothing seems to work.

Accessing Artifactory via browser GUI seems fine, the certificate seems to be fine and we can see no issues.

Any ideas would be most welcome.